# Javascript Overlapping, Set Z order of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, z-index, overlap

Ok I'm stuck. I am using opencart, and I have added the jquery zoom plugin so that the images can be magnified.

Since doing this it is now conflicting with the menu, I cant figure out what to do?

Is there any sort of way of setting a sort order of the jquery on the page. I have tried the JQuery topZIndex plugin but this failed to work.

PS: I am using the `z-index` in the css also.

I have tried:

```
#menu > ul > li {
position: relative; i also tried absolute
float: left;
z-index: 100;   
}
```

For the jqzoom I am using:

```
$(function() {
var options =
        {
            zoomType: 'innerzoom',
            zoomWidth: 800,
            zoomHeight: 400,
            showEffect:'fadeout',
            hideEffect:'fadeout',
            fadeoutSpeed: 'slow',
            preloadImages: 'true',
            preloadText: 'Loading...'

        }

$(".jqzoom").jqzoom(options);
  });
```

My problem is that the dropdown menu should go over the jqzoom image, however the drop down menu appears behind the jqzoom image. I was wondering if there is a means to set a `z-index` to jquery to set it to the back or something?

I have tried playing with the topZIndex() jquery plugin and used `$(".jqzoom").topZIndex( { increment: 0 } );` and `$(".jqzoom").topZIndex( { increment: 100 } );`

The javascript for the menu is:

```
$('#menu ul > li > a + div').each(function(index, element) {
    // IE6 & IE7 Fixes
    if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == 7 || $.browser.version == 6)) {
        var category = $(element).find('a');
        var columns = $(element).find('ul').length;

        $(element).css('width', (columns * 143) + 'px');
        $(element).find('ul').css('float', 'left');
    }       

    var menu = $('#menu').offset();
    var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();

    i = (dropdown.left + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.left + $('#menu').outerWidth());

    if (i > 0) {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + (i + 5) + 'px');
    }
});

// IE6 & IE7 Fixes
if ($.browser.msie) {
    if ($.browser.version <= 6) {
        $('#column-left + #column-right + #content, #column-left + #content').css('margin-left', '195px');

        $('#column-right + #content').css('margin-right', '195px');

        $('.box-category ul li a.active + ul').css('display', 'block'); 
    }

    if ($.browser.version <= 7) {
        $('#menu > ul > li').bind('mouseover', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        $('#menu > ul > li').bind('mouseout', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }); 
    }
}

$('.success img, .warning img, .attention img, .information img').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}); 
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question -- post example code that isn't working and show us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the jqzoom source code, the zoom popup window has a z-index of 5001. You need to set your dropdown to something higher than that.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted, i tried changing the css too...

    position: absolute; and tried relative also
    z-index: 99999;

but still no joy? :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing:

```
$("#your_dropdown_menu_id").css("z-index", 99999);
```